# Set onfocus & onblur values in symfony2 forms

Tags: symfony

I have created a form with an input field and a button in symfony2.

I want to set `onfocus="if (this.value=='email') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'email'"`

in the input box, so it will display "email" and when the user clicks it will disappear. I know how to do this in html (inside the  tag properties) but in twig all I have is `{{ form_widget(form.email) }}`

```
<form action="{{ path('newsletter_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="">{{ form_widget(form.email) }}</div>
                {{ form_row(form._token) }} 
            <button type="submit" class="emailSubmit btn" >Submit >></button>
        </form>
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add these fields as `attr` values. In your Twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'onfocus': 'if (this.value==\'email\') this.value = \'\'', 'onblur': 'if (this.value==\'\') this.value = \'email\''} }) }}
```

Comment: Almost perfect. It works after the first time you click into the input box. Before that it is empty. Can I set also a default value ?

Comment: Try `{'attr': {...}, 'data': 'default value'}`

Comment: Unfortunately not working. Still shows as empty even after cache:clear.

Comment: ` {{ form_widget(form.email, 
            {'attr': {'onfocus': 'if (this.value==\'email\') this.value = \'\'', 'onblur': 'if (this.value==\'\') this.value = \'email\''}, 
            'data': 'email'
            }) }} `

Comment: @RobertoDelgazzo  It depends on the type of your email field. It could be either `data:` or `value:`

Answer (score 0):

```
` {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'onfocus': 'if (this.value==\'email\') this.value = \'\'', 'onblur': 'if (this.value==\'\') this.value = \'email\''}, 'value': 'email' }) }} `
```